# Edit shortcode by select in JQuery/php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, shortcode

I have a table shortcode that should be edited depending on the values in a select box, but I cannot get it to work. I've come this far:

Shortcode syntax: `[table id=tableID filter="filterstring" \]` where the filter-part may be left out.

html:

```
<div>
<select class="filter-products">
<option value="all">All</option>
<option value="product1">product1</option>
<option value="product2">product2</option>
</select>
<div class="filter-table-doc">[table id=Doc /]</div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";

jQuery(".filter-products").on( "change", function() {

    var productTypeNew = jQuery(".filter-products").attr("value");

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action':'get_table_doc_shortcode',
            'product' : productTypeNew
        },
        success:function(data) {
            jQuery(".filter-table-doc").html(data);

        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

php:

```
function get_table_doc_shortcode(){
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {

        $product = $_REQUEST['product'];

        if ( $product == 'all' ) {
            $product = '[table id=Doc /]';
        }
        else {
            $product = '[table id=Doc filter="' + $product + '" /]';
        }

        return $product;
    }
   die();
} 
add_action('wp_ajax_get_table_doc_shortcode', 'get_table_doc_shortcode');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_table_doc_shortcode', 'get_table_doc_shortcode');
```

This generates an error in the log; `GET http://www.myurl.com/%3C?php%20echo%20admin_u…n-ajax.php%27);%20?%3E&action=get_table_doc_shortcode&product=product1 404 (Not Found)`.

Now I feel completely stuck and have wasted too much time on this already. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear your Javascript is being called from within a `.js` file instead of a `.php` file. This means that the PHP functionality you're using wont work. The error you're seeing is because JS is reading the string value of `"<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>"` instead of the ajax url you intended. If you're trying to access the url for `admin-ajax.php`, as per the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Administration_Side):

> Since Version 2.8, The JavaScript global variable ajaxurl can be used in case you want to separate your JavaScript code from php files into JavaScript only files. **This is true on the administration side only.**

So simply remove the line `var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";` from your code as `ajaxurl` is already defined globally.

Comment: Thank you, but doing this causes following error:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxurl is not defined` .

Comment: @Susanna, are you using your code on the front-end or inside the dashboard? As mentioned in the Quote, this is for **administration side only**. If you need access to `ajaxurl` on the front side, have a look at [this solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190297/ajaxurl-not-defined-on-front-end)

Comment: The link helped to solved the error, thanks! However, when the script logs result in console log, somehow the entire webpage is loaded - not only shortcode. Likewise when I try to load the shortcode like this `jQuery(".filter-table-doc").html(data);` instead of console.log, the entire webpage is loaded inside the div classed "filter-table-doc". Any suggestions?

Comment: when you go to your api end point.. do you get the whole site loading, or just the shortcode result? Part of me feels like you're attempting to do something that should be done another way.. i would think the better thing to do would be to change the page url when the user changes the dropdown with the correct shortcode being rendered by wordpress at page load

Comment: you're right - I went with the url solution instead, and it works brilliant! Thank you!